# Extend main spec file

Tags: ruby, rspec

I need to implement one main spec file and multiple spec files which extend the main spec file.

```
require 'pp'

RSpec.describe do

  context "modify xml tags" do

    context '#modify_trx_id_for' do
      it "modifies trx id" do
        # place hare main code
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How I can extend this spec with second rspec?

Comment: What do you mean by "extends"? What do you want to reuse on your multiples files?

Comment: I want to reuse context '#modify_trx_id_for' do in many sub rspec file.

Comment: Is this about for example creating a basic situation in DB for your tests (like a file with a specific tag)?

Comment: @Martin Well something like this will be useful. Can you show me example?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give a more complete example of the "bad" or "broken" version of your code? It sounds to me like a [shared context](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) is what you're talking about, but I can't really answer the question (other than providing that link!) without more details.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved several ways. If it is about setting up some model data, this could be done using shared fixtures (for example using [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) or the plain yml files)

Another option is to use Rspec [shared context](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context).

Taking from their example, you can create a "shared_transactions.rb" file (or whatever fits your model names) with the common code:

```
RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end

RSpec.shared_context "shared documents", :shared_context => :metadata do

  def shared_tags
    "<p>Hello</p>"
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.include_context "shared documents", :include_shared => true
end
```

The "shared_tags" will then be available in all your specs.